# How to get json response from facebook fql query in android

Tags: android

I am using an fql query to get the json response.I am new to this fql execution process.can I know in detail how to execute this query.I have seen some Listener class is using while getting the response,

SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id ='XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX'

Do I need to have anything to execute this and get the response?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
private void doFQLQuery()
{
    //get the active facebook session
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //create the fql query
    String fqlQuery = "SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id ='XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX'";
    //create a bundle for the parameters(your query)    
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
    //setup the request
    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
    {         
        public void onCompleted(Response response) 
        {
            //when the request is completed output the results to the log
            Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());
        }                  
    }); 
    //execute the request
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);       
}
```

You can use this code to execute an fql query and get the response. Whatever processing you want to to do on the results should be done in the onCompleted method.